# Rails3 Kaminari &Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, pagination, partial, kaminari

I've implemented Kaminari in my views to paginate. Now I've implemented my app to detect mobile via the railscast instructions http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices.

Pagination works fine while not in mobile. When I switch to mobile which would be index.mobile.erb, I'm getting this error.

---

ActionView::MissingTemplate in Activities#index

Showing /home/jon/cny32/app/views/activities/index.mobile.erb where line #35 raised:

Missing partial kaminari/paginator with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee], :formats=>[:mobile], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/jon/cny32/app/views"
  * "/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.4.2/app/views"
  * "/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
  * "/home/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views"

Extracted source (around line #35):

32: 
33: 
34: 
35: <%= paginate @activities %>
Rails.root: /home/jon/cny32

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/activities/index.mobile.erb:35:in `_app_views_activities_index_mobile_erb___54960106_95964060'
app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:8:in`index'
Request

Parameters:

{"format"=>"mobile"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None

---

When I take out <%= paginate @activities %>, it works but only lists a page of 10 as specified in the controller, without pagination of course.

My goal is to have pagination on the normal view and pagination on the mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have this issue too. The obvious way to copy paste kaminari views from the gem to your app changing the extension to mobile. For this you need to:

- bundle open kaminari
- go to app/views in kaminari gem
- copy kaminari folder from here and place it under your views folder
- change partials extensions from html.erb to mobile.erb(haml and slim
  ones you can delete).

But, again it is not the perfect way.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about doing it that way. Whatever works.

Comment: Same problem here. In my app I don't have any `*.mobile.erb` files and still no errors are given. Why is it that for kaminari we need to do this and for other views we don't?

Answer (score 3):

You could run the generator too:

`% rails g kaminari:views default`